# Is there any way of connecting minecraft javaPlugin to discord javaScript bot?

Tags: javascript, java, discord.js, minecraft

So basiclly, I was making a minecraft plugin, and I want to add function that alows you to log in into serwer in minecraft only if you are on discord. But i dont really know how can i call js from java.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JS bot is written using a backend framework like NodeJS, There are many ways you could achieve this. The best way being to use WebSockets.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Answer (score 0):

**basically the only way i can do this is like that:**

First of all, you have to get a database, and make a command in your js discord bot, for example `!link <code>`, so basically what does that mean, after the player enters the Minecraft server it will automatically kick him and the display the code for link his discord account, and he just has to use the command that I mentioned before to link his account, this is really simple things you can easily make it with HashMap in java.